# How to reload node_modules' jar and js?

Tags: react-native

I have some react-native questions:

1) I have added some `console.log()` in

```
node_modules\react-native\ReactAndroid\src\androidTest\assets\AndroidTestBundle.js
```

However, when I try "`react-native run-android`" in Windows command, the debug panel does not show it. Should I run another command before run-android?

2) In addition, I have changed the java files in

```
node_modules\react-native\android\com\facebook\react\react-native\0.42.3\react-native-0.42.3-sources.jar
```

but it seems that it does not auto compile the jar again. Should I run any command first?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For your first question:

The React Packager usually doesn't listen to any changes to files inside the `node_modules` folder. If you make any changes to **JS** files inside the `node_modules` folder, then you will have to kill the packager **(ctrl+c)** and start it again using `react-native start` command. Then you can see the result of modifications to JS files inside the `node_modules` folder

And for your second question:

React Packager cannot compile native code in real-time it only compiles the **JS** files and delivers them to the device. So, if you make any changes to native code **JAVA**/**Swift** or **Obj-C**(for iOS) you need to build the app again using `react-native run-android` command for Android, `react-native run-ios` for iOS simulator. (manually re-run the build through XCode if you are testing on real iPhone)

Comment: Good Job @Dani Akash. I appreciate it.